Cosmos - add explicit index and ignore undefined values
I have a cosmos container that stores documents with different data structures under a sub property, let’s call it miscellaneous, however some of the documents have common properties under miscellaneous that need to be queried.
I'm Currently using the default indexing policy but would like to swap to an explicit indexing model to reduce the amount of data being indexed under the miscellaneous property.
However this paragraph from MS docs 'All explicitly included paths have values added to the index for each item in the container, even if the path is undefined for a given item.' from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/index-policy#includeexclude-strategy
seems to suggest if I add any explicit indexes to the miscellaneous properties, all documents that don't have the specified properties will also be indexed too.
This will likely result in a larger index than under the default indexing policy as several index's need to be added under the miscellaneous property.
Is there any way to retain the behavior of the default indexing policy while specifying explicit indexes, that is undefined values are not indexed?
There is an infinite number of properties that can exist under miscellaneous, so i can not add to the excluded list properties not to index.

To mimic the default policy's behavior while using explicit indexing, limit indexing to only essential fields in miscellaneous or restructure frequently queried fields outside miscellaneous. Alternatively, consider data preprocessing to minimize undefined fields before storage.

wouldn't limiting indexing to only essential fields still differ to the default policy's behavior? such that undefined values will be added to the indexes when explicitly specifying indexes, compared to the default policy not adding undefined values to indexes.
its not really explicitly called out in the cosmos docs anywhere

You use below policy.
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path":"/*"
        },
        {
            "path": "/miscellaneous/commonProperty1/?"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        },
        {
            "path": "/miscellaneous/*"
        }
    ]
}

Here i excluded all the properties under miscellaneous and included commonproperty which is common in all the records.
By doing this you only index the common properties in all the records.
Similarly, you include all the common properties in your case.
